# firebase storage getting downloadURL problem

Tags: android

when i tried to get the download URL for my image in firebase storage I got something weird i got this result

> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@3a6d712

and here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    private Button uploadButton;
    private Button captureButton;
    ImageView imageViewBig, imageViewSmall;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        imageViewBig = findViewById(R.id.imageViewBig);
        imageViewSmall = findViewById(R.id.imageViewSmall);
        captureButton = findViewById(R.id.captureButton);
        uploadButton = findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imageViewBig.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    imageViewBig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Log.i("URL", taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

so how to get the right download URL to download the image into image view using picasso

Comment: format & compress code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [**`UploadTask`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask)

```
public class UploadTask extends StorageTask<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>
```

An controllable task that uploads and fires events for success, progress and failure. It also allows pause and resume to control the upload operation.

**`Example`**

```
final StorageReference firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

StorageReference postPhotos = firebaseStorage.child("photos/");

final StorageReference upload_Image = postPhotos.child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

//uri = uri of your file which you want to update
UploadTask uploadTask = upload_Image.putFile(uri);
           uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });
           uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        upload_Image.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    //downloadable uri
                                     Uri path = task.getResult();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: where is the variable file in this line of code come from .                                                           UploadTask uploadTask = upload_Image.putFile(Uri.fromFile(file));

Comment: @ANDROID_BIGGENER putFile takking uri of your file which you want to upadate now editted the answare and make changes to `upload_Image.putFile(uri);`

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code to upload File on firebase and get download url for that file

```
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(aadhaarPath));
        final StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("documents/" + file.getLastPathSegment());
        uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);

        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                // get the image Url of the file uploaded
                riversRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        Uri downloadUrl = uri;
                        aadharDownloadUrl = downloadUrl.toString();
                        uploadPanCard(panCardPath);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

**aadhaarPath** is file path that you selected to upload

and add this in your build .gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I save photos to Firebase storage and the image name to Firebase realtime database and than i am using Glide to load images from Firebase Storage:

```
            FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
            StorageReference imageRef = storageRef.child(PHOTO_NAME);

            GlideApp.with(mContext).load(islandRef).into(viewHolder.image);
```